# Compressing existing TIFF file in c#

Tags: c#, tiff

I have thousands of TIFF files that are all 32MB because no compression was added to them.  I need to run through them and compress each one using LZW.  To make this quick I am only compressing single page TIFF files, which are most of them.

I get a Generic GDI+ error when running this.  However, if I use a different file name when saving then it works fine.

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Data\lzwtest");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.tif");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
    int tiffpages = image1.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);
    if (tiffpages == 1)
    {
        image1.Save(@"D:\Data\lzwtest\" + file.Name, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
    }
}
```

If I change the image1.Save line to the following then it works (just adding a "test-" to the front of the file name.

```
image1.Save(@"D:\Data\lzwtest\test-" + file.Name, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any error message? Maybe inner exception?

Comment: Overwriting an image you just read is often harder than expected. Besides avoiding it in the first place, __disposing__ of it is necessary.. Also reading it with a Stream method helps. Search for 'Overwriting an existing image'!

Comment: To add what to @TaW  said, to do this, I typically read the FILE in to a byte array, then open the image from a memory stream. This lets you safely overwrite the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an intermediate store for the bitmap.

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Data\lzwtest");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.tif");
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file))) 
    {
        Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
        int tiffpages = image1.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);
        if (tiffpages == 1)
        {
             image1.Save(@"D:\Data\lzwtest\" + file.Name, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that GDI+ locks the source of the bitmap, whether it's a file or a stream really. in this case, we don't care if the MemoryStream is locked.

*And I wish the devs of GDI+ hours of sitting on a uncomfortable chair for this "Generic GDI+ error". With no inner exception and no other explanation.*